# How to access ui of xampp running on linux command line

Tags: linux, xampp, amazon-ami

I have installed xampp on linux (command line version with no gui).
I am using Amazon Linux AMI.

The installation is successful and i got xampp up and running.

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-4...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
```

However i am not able to access the xampp ui from browser.

I am accessing http://(public ip of the linux ami)

Is there anything else required to access the ui.

Answer (score 1):

I did some R&D around the problem and found out that the security group (linked to the amazon instance) did not allow http traffic.

Edited security group to allow http traffic and issue was resolved.

XAMPP UI can be accessed now using the public DNS or public IP.